# Merge two pivot table or group by rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

We are exporting .xlsx data. For 1 to n relations, we get duplicate entries.

We usual bypass this problem by using pivot tables and by placing the columns we need to group under "rows".

We now need to produce reports that contain two 1 to n relations. We tried to use pivot tables again, but we couldn't group the rows correctly. Instead, we made two different pivot tables that we are now wishing to merge.

This is our file:
[image: Input file]

And this is the two pivot table we made from:
[image: two pivot tables]

We wish to group them by "ID + Company name" column like this:

[image: Results made in Paint]

Is there a way to do so in Excel?

Comment: From what you describe, I'd think Power Query (available in Excel 2010+) might be the way to go.  Exactly how to approach depends more on exactly what you want for results, and the format.

Comment: Using PT for this will be not a good choice,,, since has very limited scope in regard of proper data illustration while using on multiple groups,,, better think for another tools !!